# How to fetch and save particular records from Rich TextBox in C# Windows Application

Tags: c#

I want to get and save particular records from Rich TextBox in C# example I want to get Total Amount, Invoice No, and Date following records,

- Owner Name: Peter
- VAT 796.24
- TOTAL AMOUNT 16,830.04
- Personal ID 6107300000
- Account No. 5379250817
- Invoice No & Date 537925730425 - 07/03/2022
- Premise ID 5379250281

**Expecting Result:**

- *16,830.04*
- *537925730425*
- *07/03/2022*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can split RichTextBox text to lines and check each line if it starts with what data you want. Here an example:

```
string text = richTextBox1.Text;
foreach(string line in text.Split('\n'))
{
    if (line.StartsWith("TOTAL AMOUNT"))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(line.Split(' ')[2]);
    }
    else if (line.StartsWith("Account No."))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(line.Split(' ')[2]);
    }
    else if (line.StartsWith("Account No."))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(line.Split(' ')[2]);
    }
    else if (line.StartsWith("Invoice No & Date"))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(line.Split('-')[1]);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
16,830.04
5379250817
 07/03/2022
```